# Best mysql field type for storing content hashtags/keywords

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need to store user posts/comments and each post has a post_hashtags field (like keywords) ...

What MySQL data type would be best for this post_hashtags ?

I need to later be able to select all posts that contain one given hashtag (exact match), for example when displaying all relavant posts at an url like

`www.example.com/tag/car`

Normally I would store them in a `text` type field and delimit them like this:

`[car][red][engine]`

That way I can lookup with `SELECT * from user_posts WHERE post_hashtags LIKE '%[car]%'`

Is there a better data type for this ? 
These hashtags should contain any alpha-numeric values and are NOT a limited set of possible pre-defined values.

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly answer your question: varchar(20) is a good pick.

For the best performance, use a separate table to store your tags:

```
Table tags
----------
id integer PK
tag varchar(20)
```

This link might be helpful: [Best way to store "tags" for speed in enormous table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280045/best-way-to-store-tags-for-speed-in-enormous-table)

Hope this helps.